# Client found response content type of 'application/pdf', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message:

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-to-pdf

Hi all I have written this code in a web-service http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx as follows

```
[WebMethod]
    public void convert(string strURL)
    {
        HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        string url = strURL;
        byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(url);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        // let the browser know how to open the PDF document, attachment or inline, and the file name
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=ConvertHtmlPart.pdf; size={0}",
                    pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

        // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

        // call End() method of HTTP response to stop ASP.NET page processing
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

I added this as a reference in my project from my local host but when trying to convert I am getting an exception as `Client found response content type of 'application/pdf', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message:` can some one help me.

Comment: try removing the size from the header `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ConvertHtmlPart.pdf");`

Comment: Didn't worked `SearchAndResQ`

Comment: Where is this exception being raised? on which line? I suspect it is on the line: byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(url);

Comment: `Quinton Bernhardt` after response was ended and returned to `  obj.convert(txtUrl.Text.ToString());` exception was raising

Comment: I think this is `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();` causing the exception

Answer (score 0):

".ToString()" - it is not necessary

[is it?](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/paytonbyrd/successfully-stream-a-pdf-through-https-1554)